# DIY steel frame kitchen cabinets -- is this a good or bad idea?

Tags: cabinets, custom-cabinetry

I'm planning to build my own kitchen cabinets, and I understand the basic methods used for American and European styles.

For some reason, I'm tempted by the idea of using steel frames instead of the classic plywood box, and mounting either wooden face frames to that, or even attempting European flush doors/drawers directly to the steel frame.

Has this been done? Google doesn't turn up anything useful for me on this question. I know people have done cabinets with cheap 2x4s so I am sure it *could* be done, but I'm sure there must be some caveats I'm not thinking of.

With the prices of lumber right now, I think it might even be cheaper, and certainly could be stronger.

Comment: There are metal cabinets available for purchase. Perhaps if you Google that you will see how they are constructed.

Comment: @JimStewart the only such cabinets I am aware of are sheet metal construction, welded or otherwise. I am thinking of an open, built-in tube or angle iron frame.

Comment: It can be done.  Something like metal shelving.  Cutting/drilling/attachment is more labour intensive than what wood would be.  Probably need bolts and nuts or welding instead of screws.  All metal should be painted/primed before covering.

Comment: kitchen is a wet area, consider rust prevention.

Comment: Kitchen like the locker room; awesome look? :/ (but hey, each to their own)

Comment: Aluminum might be easier to work with than steel.  Easier to drill/cut most times, and don't worry about rust.

Comment: This is really an opinion question, there were metal cabinets in some homes I want to say pre 50’s era, I remember an old timer that wanted an updated look but because of field mice had to keep metal skinned cabinets. We glued laminate on for a new wood look and he was happy with his new cabinet look. So sure but as an opinion this is off topic.

Comment: I don't get it. Buying prefab steel or aluminum cabinets? Or scratch building with a metal brake and metalworking skills?  Do you have the skills to pay the bills? (and the brake and shear)?

Comment: As the question states, metal frame with wood doors. They would be all wood on the outside, just a skeleton of steel.

Comment: I can't think of any benefit commensurate with the problems.